# Para que serve o serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, interface, serialização, desserialização

Se não declaro essa constante (`serialVersionUID`) em uma classe que implementa a interface `Serializable`, recebo um *warning*. Mas pra quê essa constante serve, afinal? O valor dela interfere na serialização do objeto?

Answer (score 6):

O `serialVersionUID` serve para rastrear a compatibilidade de versões serializadas das classes.

Isso ocorre porque se você serializa uma instância de uma classe `X` e salva em um arquivo, e algum tempo depois altera a classe `X` e desserializa aquela instância, pode ser que os dados desserializados não sejam compatíveis com a nova versão da classe, uma vez que ela sofreu uma alteração.

E como você define qual é a versão da classe? Com o `serialVersionUID`. É para isso que ele serve.

A ideia é que se você for criar uma classe serializável `A`, você declare algo como `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` nela para definir que essa é a primeira versão da classe. Depois, se você fizer alguma alteração estrutural incompatível com versões anteriores, você mudará o `serialVersionUID` para `2L`. Em uma outra alteração, mudará para `3L` e assim por diante. Obviamente, se a alteração for pequena e nenhuma incompatibilidade for introduzida, você não deve alterar o `serialVersionUID`.

Se você fizer uma mudança estrutural incompatível na classe e não mudar o `serialVersionUID`, a desserialização de uma instância incompatível vai falhar.

Se você quiser ser capaz de ler uma versão diferente da classe a ser desserializada, você pode implementar o método [`readObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a2971) e lá, ler o `serialVersionUID` necessário. O método [`readObjectNoData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a6053) também pode ser útil.

Finalmente, se você não definir nenhum `serialVersionUID`, então um será gerado automaticamente para você a partir de um hash levando em conta o nome da classe, das superclasses, das interfaces implementadas e dos membros da classe (campos, métodos e construtores). Isso significa que é muito fácil que aconteça do `serialVersionUID` gerado automaticamente mudar mesmo que não ocorram alterações significativas na classe. Por esse motivo, é recomendável você sempre colocar o `serialVersionUID` explicitamente.

Links adicionais para maiores informações:

- [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) - da Oracle.
- [Entendendo o serialVersionUID](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-serialversionuid/) - da Caelum.
- [Pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285793/540552)

Comment: Victor sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade ou estender a resposta, o que nivel de mudança estrurural poderia ocorrer problemas? Mudar implementação dentro de um método qualquer, sem alterar a sua assinatura é considerado uma mudança estrutural que altera o `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: @diegofm Sem mudar a estrutura do método, provavelmente não. Mas acrescentar algum método privado ou alterar a assinatura de um existente já é o suficiente para mudar o `serialVersionUID`. O acréscimo ou a alteração de uma classe interna pode fazer o compilador criar alguns métodos com visibilidade de pacote para dar acesso de coisas da classe externa à classe interna, e isso também pode acabar por alterar o `serialVersionUID`. Assim sendo, em geral, nunca é seguro presumir que o `serialVersionUID` não vai mudar se o mesmo não estiver definido explicitamente.